# raspbian python virtualenv not working on thumb drive

Tags: python, virtualenv, raspberry-pi

In raspian I can make virtual envs in my home directory but when I try to make a virtual env in a folder on my thumb drive it says the os prevents it ("operation not permitted").  Is this a known issue?

Comment: do you mean raspbian ?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to format my drive with linux partition - not fat partition.